# Where does yml reading code belong in MVC (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have a some application specific data in a yml file. This data is required by 2 controllers in my app. Where should I place the code which fetches and returns data from yml?
Should it be in Application Controller, or in a parent controller, or in helpers, or a module, or a model ?
My feeling is that since this code would return application specific data from yml, hence it should actually be in a model. But since this data is not actually coming from a table, is there a better place for this logic than a module?

Edit1:

Data in yml is a list of 10 hand-picked movies in each of 5 different genres. So, the yml contains 5 category names and 10 movies in each category. The code is supposed to fetch and return this data as a list of hashes :

```
[{
   category_name: Sci-fi,
   movies: [movie1, movie2,...]
  },
  {
   category_name: Horror,
   movies: [movie1, movie2,...]
  },
  .
  .
}]
```

This data is used to populate one of the pages in the app.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the data you are trying to get?

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb Added into the question

Comment: According to your example, better to use models for this. Controllers, views or services definitely not good choice.

Comment: No.  It has to be a module that is included wherever needed